# 10 Coins being tossed and calculating certain probabilities

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Last lecture the professor addressed us with a problem that I I'v may misunderstood but I am certain it is one of the two .

In both problems we have 10 regular (no biased) coins on a table , and we wish to flip them .

In the first version of the problem let us assume we are flipping them all at the same time , so we consider the first flip as a flip for all the coins together . 
Now after each flip , the coins that land heads will be removed of the group (like collected) , the question is , find the Probability that we would have collected all the 10 coins by the x-th flip , so the random variable X is the number of flips needed .

My approach was a bit simple even though the professor said it was a hard problem .  I first found the probability that X is bigger than a value x , which means it took at least more than x trails to collect all the coins , now I related this expression to "at least one coin failed x times" which is shallowly calculated P(X>x) = 10 * 0.5^x    , the 10 being that we have 10 possible coins to choose from to fail in general .

Then we obtain P(X=x) = P(X>x-1)-P(X>x) = 10*0.5^(x-1) .

Any thoughts on why my supposition and answer is incorrect , and if you can , a detailed explanation to your method .

The second version of this problem is that we count the singular flips on each coin aside instead of one big flip on the group , which is impossible so I'm putting my bet that the first version of the problem is the correct one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , we start by considering cumulative probabilities , Probability that X is smaller than a number x means at least one H in x times , which is the complement of no H's . So P(X<=x) = (1-0.5^x)^10
Thus P(X=x)=P(X<=x)-P(X<=(x-1))

Answer (score 3):

The probability that a single coin comes up $T$ $x$ times in a row is exactly $.5^x$.  Therefore the probability that this one coin comes up $H$ at least once in $x$ flips is $1-.5^x$.  It follows that the probability that $10$ independent coins all come up $H$ at least once in $x$ flips is $(1-.5^x)^{10}$.

Your starting remark isn't correct.  Knowing that one coin survives with probability $p$ does not imply that at least one of $10$ survives with probability $10p$.  Think, for example, about throwing $10$ coins once....the probability that one comes up $T$ is $\frac 12$ but it is clearly false to say that this means that the probability that at least one comes up $T$ is $10\times \frac 12= 5$. The trouble is that you are counting cases repeatedly (you count the case where the first two come up $T$ at least twice, once for the first coin and again for the second).

Comment: You are correct on the point that I am counting cases over and over again but in your answer aren't you like ignoring the fact that we are removing some coins before others and shouldn't we take into account any of those changes ? Like will your method only count the number of times until every coin has shown heads once ? Or will it count cases like : x=2 ,  and in the first and second throw all the coins show success , which shouldn't be the case or else x would have been 1

Comment: I am pretending that each coin is tossed $x$ times...of course, we know that each coin is "removed" after $H$ comes up.  I am just distinguishing between "strings of length $x$ in which $H$ comes up at least once" and "the string of $x$ $T's$."  All of the first sort are removed exactly once.

Comment: Yes but what do you think would be the solution to my problem

Comment: My solution works for your problem!  You remove any coin that comes up $H$ at least once in $x$ trials.  Doesn't matter which of the $x$ trials comes up $H$.  Doesn't matter if it "would have" come up $H$ more than once.

Comment: My advice:  go through my calculation carefully for a modest sized $x$, say $x=4$.  I am claiming that the probability that a coin comes up $H$ at least once in $4$ trials is $1-.5^4=\frac {15}{16}$, because the only alternative is $TTTT$.   Check that this is the same as what you want.  You remove $H$ (prob $\frac 12$) and $TH$ (prob $\frac 14$) and $TTH$ (prob $\frac 18$) and $TTTH$ (prob $\frac 1{16}$).  Hence the probability of removal is $\frac 12 +\frac 14+\frac 18 + \frac 1{16}=\frac {8+4+2+1}{16}=\frac {15}{16}$.

Comment: About your formula , if you the summation with x going to infinity (I used 30 as infinity) you get way more than 1

Comment: Why on earth would you add them up?  That doesn't represent the probability of any event, so there's no reason at all for the sum to be bounded by $1$.  Of course, it makes sense to let $x$ tend to $\infty$....but then you get $1$ as you'd expect (if you toss the coin infinitely often you are sure to get $H$ at some point).

Comment: Shouldn't the events be connected to each other and add up to the certain event ? Yet again your argument makes sense , that the probability of x goes to infinity is 1

Comment: The events are not mutually exclusive, so the probabilities do not add.  The event "each coin has come up $H$ at least once in $5$ flips" contains  the event "each coin has come up $H$ at least once in $4$ flips".  You can only add the probabilities of mutually exclusive events.

Comment: I guess I came to understand the reason for mutual exclusion , I will consult my professor and reply again